# Push a View by converting a string to a class?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flash-builder

I am currently working in Flashbuilder 4.6 creating a mobile application and I wish to push the users to a view by based on the menu item they select. My code below shows how I have tried to convert a string from a selected list item into a class object and then pass that into the parameter for the pushView:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.*;            
        import spark.components.SplitViewNavigator;
        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
        import spark.managers.PersistenceManager;
        import spark.skins.mobile.SplitViewNavigatorSkin;

        public var menuAC:ArrayCollection;          
        public var j_array:Array = [{label:"Home", data:"NLView"}, 
            {label:"All Jobs", data:"JList"}, 
            {label:"Company Profiles", data:"SView"}, 
            {label:"Search By Sector", data:"JView"}];


        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            var selectedItem:String = new String(list.selectedItem.data);
            //trace("Selected Item = " + selectedItem);
            var splitNavigator:SplitViewNavigator = navigator.parentNavigator as SplitViewNavigator;
            var detailNavigator:ViewNavigator = splitNavigator.getViewNavigatorAt(0) as ViewNavigator;
            splitNavigator.hideViewNavigatorPopUp();

            if(list.selectedItem.data == "NewListView")
            {
                var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(selectedItem) as Class;                 
                trace("View Class = " + myClass);
                detailNavigator.pushView(myClass);
            }
            else if(list.selectedItem.data)
            {

            }


        }

        protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {

            if(data.view == "JSFilt")
            {
                menuAC = new ArrayCollection(j_array);  
            }

            list.dataProvider = menuAC;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var splitNavigator:SplitViewNavigator = navigator.parentNavigator as SplitViewNavigator;
            var detailNavigator:ViewNavigator = splitNavigator.getViewNavigatorAt(1) as ViewNavigator;
            splitNavigator.hideViewNavigatorPopUp();
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:BitmapImage width="100%" height="100%" source="@Embed('assets/images/sidebg.png')" fillMode="repeat"/>
<s:BitmapImage horizontalCenter="0" top="5" width="175" height="130" source="@Embed('assets/images/G_S_Logo_170x130.png')"/>

<s:List id="list" left="0" right="0"
        color="0xFFFFFF" contentBackgroundColor="0x101010"
        fontSize="20" width="280"
        alternatingItemColors="[0x202020,0x2a2a2a]"
        top="140" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="200"
        downColor="0x70B2EE"
        selectionColor="0x70B2EE"
        change="list_changeHandler(event)"> 
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer messageStyleName="myFontStyle" fontSize="22" height="70" 
                                labelField="label"
                                messageField="" 
                                />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>       
</s:List>
```

I have also tried using the following command which also did not work:

```
var viewClass:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(selectedItem)));
```

Has anyone got anyidea how to look at a value selected on a list and then use that string name to push the App to the view as the pushView method wont accept a string??

---

Thanks for the suggestions and I like the idea of adding the class to the array and then passing that to the pushView. I had tried that in the past and it didnt work so I tried your method with the code below:

```
public var jobs_array:Array = [{label:"Home", data:"NewListView", class:NewListView},
                {label:"All", data:"JList"}, 
                {label:"C Prof's", data:"SView"}, 
                {label:"S By S", data:"JSView"}];
```

As you can see I have tried to implement what you suggested on the first line and I get the following errors:

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before rightbrace.
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before class.
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
```

This must a simple syntax thing but I cant see it, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var imageClass:Class=getDefinitionByName("com.robaldred.composers."+imgclass) as Class;
```

Please add the packages name like this: `com.robaldred.composers.`

Answer (score 0):

`getDefinitionByName(selectedItem)` is almost what you want, but not quite. See, `selectedItem` is one of the items from your array, say `{label:"All Jobs", data:"JList"}`, not just `"JList"`.

`getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(selectedItem))` is definitely not what you want, as `getQualifiedClassName` will return the fully qualified class name of `selectedItem`. In this case, that would be `Object`. Then `getDefinitionByName` will return the Object class.

---

`getDefinitionByName(selectedItem.data)` should work for you just fine. `selectedItem.data` should be `JList`, for example, and then `getDefinitionByName` should return the JList Class object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put a reference to the Class itself in the data, and don't worry about using a String to represent it.

Your data items would look like this:

```
var data:Array = [
{ label: "Item 1", class: ClassToUseForItem1 },
{ label: "Item 2", class: ClassToUseForItem2 },
{ label: "Item 3", class: ClassToUseForItem3 } ];
```

And now you can do `pushView(list.selectedItem.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. here is the answer for binding spark viewstack slelected child using a string
var str:String="roof";
viewstack.selectedChild=NavigatorContent(viewstack.getChildByName(str));